# JQuery function can't be called in called in Hogan template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hogan.js

I want to simply overlay one part of an image over another. Below is my image:
[image: Stars image]

And what I have right now is the following:

HTML:

```
<script type="text/template" id="hit-template">
  {{#hits}}
  <div class="hit">
    <div class="hit-content">
      <h3 class="hit-name">Name</h3>
      <span class="stars">4.0</span> 
    </div>
  {{/hits}}
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.hit-content {
    font-size: 13px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

//This CSS class shows all the grey stars on my page
.hit .hit-content span.stars, span.stars span {
    height: 35px;
    width: 185px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: url('/resources/graphics/stars-icons.png') 0 0 repeat-x;
}

//This CSS class should be to show only the orange stars on my page
.hit .hit-content span.stars span {
    background: url('/resources/graphics/stars-icons.png') 0 -36px repeat-x;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Is there any way I can get it so that I can overlay the orange stars over the grey stars to show certain star ratings?

I've tried:

Javascript:

```
$hits = $('#hits');
var hitTemplate = Hogan.compile($('#hit-template').text());
$hits.html(hitTemplate.render(content));


$.fn.stars = function() {
    return $(this).each(function() {
        // Get the value
        var val = parseFloat($(this).html());
        // Make sure that the value is in 0 - 5 range, multiply to get width
        var size = Math.max(0, (Math.min(5, val))) * 16;
        // Create stars holder
        var $span = $('<span />').width(size);
        // Replace the numerical value with stars
        $(this).html($span);
    });
}

$(function() {
    $('span.stars').stars();
});
```

For whatever reason, the `$('span.stars').stars();` call never is executed and I'm not sure why. Can anyone explain to me why this is happening? Thanks!

Edit: New Attempt with Promise:

```
function renderHits(content) {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        $hits.html(hitTemplate.render(content));
        resolve();
    });
    promise.then(function(val) {
        $('span.stars').stars();
    });
};
$.fn.stars = function() { 
  return this.each(function() {
    // Get the value
    console.log("HI");
    var val = parseFloat($(this).html()); 
    // Make sure that the value is in 0 - 5 range, multiply to get width
    var size = Math.max(0, (Math.min(5, val))) * 36.5; 
    // Create stars holder
    var $span = $('<span> </span>').width(size); 
    // Replace the numerical value with stars
    $(this).empty().append($span);
  });
}
```

Comment: Did you try to put it in `document.ready` https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @JaredChu Yes, I put it within a `$(document).ready(function () {

});`

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/d1j94803/, your function is called.

Comment: @JaredChu Yeah, I think its jsut that my Hogan Template is preventing it from being called. Is there a way I can use `$(document).on` somehow to call my stars function instead? I am noticing in the code there seems to be some jQuery being performed using `$(document).on`

Comment: the problem is `javascript is Non-Sequential Execution`, it mean `$hits.html(hitTemplate.render(content));` is not fully execute before `$('span.stars').stars();` execute. pls take a look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: @JaredChu I have a function called `renderHits` which calls `$hits.html(hitTemplate.render(content));`. If I put

`$(function() {
    $('span.stars').stars();
});` After the `$hits.html(hitTemplate.render(content));`, the code is still not executed. Any ideas why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129314/discussion-between-jared-chu-and-user1871869).